# two hyperlinks in the same li tag

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to modify/update a webmail script where i want to have two hyperlinks inside a li tag without the second link wrapping to the next line. I also want to have the whole `<li>` to be clickable, similar to what yahoo mail has.
I have searched on here and googled but can't find anything that works.

this is what isnt working:

```
<div class="vertical">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Folders</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sent</a></li><br/>
<li><a href="#">Trash </a><a href="#">[empty]</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the code i have so far including the css that i cant get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4gQC/33/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is up with the code there? `<br>`s and float left together? A random `<span>`? I do not understand!

Comment: The `display:block` of the `a` cause it to break lines for every link.

Comment: Actually, the html is just fine and does do what you want. It's the css that changes things. Please include the relevant css here.

Comment: @kyle - if i take out the `<span>` and the `<br/>` it turns into a ladder.. try it yourself !

Comment: I did, I also removed the float: left; from CSS. IT looked exactly the same. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/z4gQC/33/

Comment: @kyle - the code above is doing what i had at the start !. I would like the whole line to be click-able and also the empty on the same line as the empty. It seems that if i remove display-block it only makes the text of the a tag clickable.

Comment: That's the point, you don't _need to float the lis left and use breaks!_ It's unneeded markup!

Comment: @kyle: ok, i see that now.. but the trash and empty are on different lines in you last example. so back to square one !

Comment: Aye, I was just pointing out the craziness of the markup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/z4gQC/26/

Change your CSS to:

```
div.vertical
{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
}
div.vertical ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.vertical li
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;   
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
}
div.vertical a
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width:50px;   
}
div.vertical a:link,div.vertical a:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#666666;
    text-align:left;
    padding:8px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div.vertical li:hover,div.vertical a:active
{
    background-color:#d4d4d4;
}
span 
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

---

**Edit:**

OP requested the [empty] one to be right aligned.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/z4gQC/35/

Add a class to `<a href="#">[empty]</a>` as

```
<a href="#" class="right">[empty]</a>
```

And add the following to your CSS:

```
div.vertical a.right:link, div.vertical a.right:visited{
    text-align: right;
}
```

​

Comment: thanks, this works. is there a way to make the [empty] to be right aligned ?

Comment: is it possible to make the whole line clickable while still having the empty on the same line as the trash ? By changing display:block the a tag is now only clickable.

Comment: see the updated answer and fiddle. What do you mean by "make the whole line clickable"?

Comment: if you look at the fiddle code, if you move the cursor over the words of the links it is clickable (hand icon appears) however if you move over the rest of the line (li tag) its still ighlighted, but you cant click on it. My orginal version was clickable on the whole menu line. Apart from this its all perfect..

Comment: i modified it a bit: [http://jsfiddle.net/z4gQC/43/](http://jsfiddle.net/z4gQC/43/) which gives the effect i want.. can you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: ok... I have tweaked a bit of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/z4gQC/44/ Mainly just moved the inline styles to classes in the CSS and tweaked the widths.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the clicked item highlighted with css, as the page doesnt reload, the folder that is selected is loaded into a iframe using the target option. I have done this before with javascript, however i would like to not use javascript if possible.

Comment: @DavoA - no, it isn't possible in pure CSS as far as I know CSS :) it will have to be javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Make links floating:

```
div.vertical a {
  float: left;
}
```

And make hover effect with `li` tag, not `a` tag:

```
div.vertical li {
  background-color:#f3f3f3;
}

div.vertical li:hover {
  background-color:#d4d4d4;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z4gQC/31/

Comment: i want the whole line to be highlighted, it look wonky if just making the a tag the hover. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try this change your css to this

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4gQC/34/)

```
 div.vertical
{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
}
div.vertical ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.vertical li
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;   
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
}
div.vertical a
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width:50px;
float:right    
}

div.vertical a:first-child{ float:left}

div.vertical a:link,div.vertical a:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#666666;
    text-align:left;
    padding:8px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div.vertical li:hover,div.vertical a:active
{
    background-color:#d4d4d4;
}
span 
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

Comment: yes there is way. check current css code. Replace this to old one

Answer (score -2):

Simply correct your css to :

```
div.vertical a
{
    display:inline-block; 
}
```

instead of :

```
div.vertical a
{
display:block; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4gQC/18/

Comment: Exactly what did you change here? Just adding whitespace won't change anything...

Comment: @Arjan Ahmad changed `block` to `inline-block`

Comment: I didn't down vote, but your fiddle is *not* doing what the OP asked for.